# how to loop the <tr> of a table according to the number of days in a month?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to display the year and the month of a date in the form2 also looped the  number times of the number of days of a month corresponds, I hope to understand me, see source code and understand you,I hope to understand me, see source code and understand you .

```
  <div id="form1">
   <div class="form-group">
     <label>Date:</label>
      <input type="date" id="datePicker" name="date" class="form-control" placeholder="date naissance">
    </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-offset-5 ">
      <button class="btn btn-success " id="hide">valider</button>
  </div>
  </div>
 <!--form 2-->
<div id="form2">
  <div class="form-group col-md-offset-5 ">
  <button class="btn btn-success add-all" type="submit" >Pointage men</button>
</div>
    <h4>YEAR : <span id="year"></span></h4>
    <h4>MONTH : <span id="month"></span></h4>
  <table class="table table-bordered" id="mytable">
  <tr>
    <th><input type="checkbox" id="check_all"></th>
    <th>jour</th>
    <th>THS</th>
  </tr>
   (for i=1 to NbreDayMonth){
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"></td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td><input type="text"  class="form-control" value="2" /></td>
  </tr>
                    }
  </table>
```

voila code jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#check_all').on('click', function(e) {
    if ($(this).is(':checked', true)) {
      $(".checkbox").prop('checked', true);
    } else {
      $(".checkbox").prop('checked', false);
    }
  });
  $('.checkbox').on('click', function() {
    if ($('.checkbox:checked').length == $('.checkbox').length) {
      $('#check_all').prop('checked', true);
    } else {
      $('#check_all').prop('checked', false);
    }
  });
    var now = new Date();
    var day = ("0" + now.getDate()).slice(-2);
    var month = ("0" + (now.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
    var today = now.getFullYear()+"-"+(month)+"-"+(day) ;
    $('#datePicker').val(today);
});
     $(document).ready(function(){
         $("#hide").click(function(){
            let valu = $('#datePicker').val();
            let selectedDate = new Date(valu);
            var selectedYear = selectedDate.getFullYear();
            var selectedMonth = selectedDate.getMonth() + 1;
             $('#dateE').text(valu);
             $('.year').val(selectedYear).parent().prepend(selectedYear);
             $('.month').val(selectedMonth).parent().prepend(selectedMonth);

             $("#form1").hide();
            $("#form2").show();
          });
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/f5dzjntL/1/

it is easy to add any HTML tags by using append()
so you can add this function to create the TR tags :

```
function addTr(day){
 let html = `<tr>
    <td><input name=chk_"`+day+`" type="checkbox" class="checkbox"></td>
    <td>`+day+`</td>
    <td><input name=t_"`+day+`" type="text"  class="form-control" value="2" /></td>
  </tr>`;

  $('#mytable').append(html);
 }
```

and then create for loop to repeat this function with the number of the days

```
   for(i = 1; i < selectedDay+1; i++){
      addTr(i);          
   }
```

check the full code on JsFiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/f5dzjntL/1/

Comment: thx for answer bro but  why it does not work for some months for ex month 2

Comment: new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();

Comment: oh that's good, it's me who write a date false "30/02/2019" and the month 2 to 28 days